# Automatically delete rows in mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, cron

I have a site where users can choose their own username --but only for 3 days. So after three days, the username is available for someone else to choose. I set up my mysql table so that it inserts a row with the username along with the date it was created when someone chooses their username. What is the best way to deal with my objective? Should I automatically delete that row after 3 days in Mysql (using Cron?) or is it possible to reach my goal some other way?

Comment: Run a cron job every day to delete accounts older than 3 days.

Comment: Or use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Comment: If you have a timestamp of when you created a username, you could just check if a username is 3 days or older when checking if the username is allowed. This means disabling the `UNIQUE` index for the username column, if you were using that... I would recommend this over deleting, information is power :P

Comment: Is using cron the most effective (and quickest) way of doing this on a production site? Especially on a hosting site.

Comment: The query will be the same: either as cron job or as MySQL event. How many rows will it be?

Comment: I would not consider a cron job or an event for this, you can simply invalidate usernames based on the date created in SQL. So anyone who logs in, the query might be select * from users where username=:username and created_date > - 3 days. This approach will mean that you table has many records, but then you can delete old records on weekly or monly, etc. schedule rather than every day.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cron, but you could save some server time by just deleting or updating the rows when and if someone chooses a name that has been take and the name is older than 3 day.

1. User signs up, chooses a username
2. Check to see if username is taken, if not proceed as usual
3. If username is taken, check to see if it's older than 3 days
4. If the username is older than three days, either update it or delete it and create a new one.

If you use this method you will have to employ a similar method in the login script to prevent expired usernames from logging in.